# BitBucket Pipeline ssh to Digital Ocean Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: ssh, bitbucket, digital-ocean, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm sure this is not the first question for BitBucket Pipeline and Digital Ocean, but I have gone through several similar posts without any luck.

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: SSH to Digital Ocean and update docker image
        script:
          - ssh -i ~/.ssh/config root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
          - docker rm -f mycontainer
          - docker image rm -f myrepo/imagename:tag
          - docker pull myrepo/imagename:tag
          - docker run --name mycontainer -p 12345:80 -d=true --restart=always myrepo/imagename:tag
        services:
          - docker
```

Here is the SSH Key in my BitBucket repository
[image]

Here is what the BitBucket Pipeline shows to me:

[image]

How can I resolve this?

Comment: why downvoted? Please do not down vote without an explanation, it's not helpful. I am happy to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a key problem - it's that the Pipelines container does not act as a normal terminal, but `ssh` expects a terminal under normal operation. You should be able to pass the command(s) to be run as arguments to the SSH command: `ssh -i /path/to/key user@host "docker rm -f mycontainer && docker image rm -f myrepo/imagename:tag"` etc.

Comment: hi Jim, as my BitBucket free pipeline time has been used up. I wrote a .bat file which has the: ssh -i /path/to/key user@host "command1 && command2" and ran it locally. But still, it throws error: No such container: gvcontainer. please help